# MS Graph API Insufficient permissions when using Python SDK, sufficient when doing normal HTTP requests

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, authorization, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to migrate my usage of Graph API from doing http requests via `requests` to using the Python SDK. I was using the `acquire_token_by_username_password` method and requests were going through correctly. When migrating to utilize the Python SDK, I'm creating my client like:

```
credential = UsernamePasswordCredential(
        client_id=self._client_id,
        username=username,
        password=password,
    )
    return GraphServiceClient(credential, self._scopes)
```

and then attempting a request like:
`await client.users.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)`

However, with the same credentials as I was using in the HTTP method, I'm getting:

```
  APIError
        Code: 403
        message: None
        error: MainError(additional_data={}, code='Authorization_RequestDenied', details=None, inner_error=InnerError(additional_data={}, client_request_id='53e56211-cd3d-47d5-b3fb-b6dacd6088a8', date=DateTime(2024, 2, 25, 11, 10, 15, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), odata_type=None, request_id='4b92be4e-d60a-4040-bcb4-e8d11a636879'), message='Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.', target=None)
```

I have attempted re consenting for the (delegated) permissions in azure; not sure what else can I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if the user or service principal does not have required **permissions** or **roles** to perform the operation.

Initially, I too got **same error** when I passed **`User.Read`** in scopes that is not enough to list users:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to add at least <kbd>User.Read.All</kbd> **Delegated** permission in your app registration by granting **admin consent** to it:

[image]

When I ran below modified code by changing **scope** value to *User.Read.All*, I got **response** with users successfully like this:

```py
import asyncio
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from azure.identity import UsernamePasswordCredential

credential = UsernamePasswordCredential(
       client_id="appId",
       username="sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
       password="xxxxxxxxxx",
   )

scopes=['User.Read.All']
client = GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes=scopes)

async def get_users():
    try:
        users = await client.users.get()
        for user in users.value:
            print(user.display_name)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

asyncio.run(get_users())
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[List users - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: Interesting. Does this mean I need to change the scopes for every Graph API endpoint request? I was under the, perhaps mistaken, impression that I could use the default scopes so long as the application registered in Azure had the correct delegated permissions.

Comment: Did it work when you changed scope to `User.Read.All`?

Comment: When you use `/.default` as scope with username password flow, token will be generated with all **Delegated** permissions that are granted in the application. But in rare cases where it's not working, it's better to try with scopes that are specific to API calls.

Comment: It worked when I changed it to `User.Read.All`, I didn't change it in other flows and left it to `/.default` and it worked. Guess it's one of those rare cases!